# Как блокировками может быть реализован уровень изоляции транзакций Serializable?

Tags: sql, база-данных, serializable, транзакции

Концепция этого уровня изоляции и других понятна.
И если говорить о других уровнях, то примерно понятно как их можно реализовать блокировками.
Вот примерное понимание других уровней без углублений:

- Read Uncommited - добавляет эксклюзивную блокировку на каждую операцию записи, которая завершает свое действие сразу после записи (не дожидаясь конца транзакции)
- Read Commited - добавляем к прошлому уровню разделяемую блокировку на чтение, которая завершает свое действие сразу после чтения
- Repeatable Read -  вместо Read Commited блокировка на чтение завершает свое действие только после завершения транзакции.

Но как делают Serializable в таком случае? Тонкости реализации может и отличные, но хотелось бы хоть на поверхностном уровне понимать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Блокировки взятые в Serializable транзакции по строкам, которые были в ней изменены остаются активными после завершения данной транзакции, до тех пор пока не будут завершены все другие Serializable транзакции, которые были начаты до завершения текущей. В случае если другая Serializable транзакция при чтении данных наткнется на такую блокировку она будет отменена и выдана ошибка сериализации, по которой прикладной код может повторить транзакцию с самого начала.

Данный механизм используется как минимум postgresql, согласно [документации](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/transaction-iso#xact-serializable)

Comment: Ответ проверил на описании проблемы Чтение «фантомов» - работает. Можно добавить источник какой-то, что бы было понятно это вообще по всем базам информация или это от конкретного вендора описание. Или может вы сами придумали только что, мой первоначальный вопрос такое тоже допускал :)

Comment: @John Ссылку на документацию добавил. На самом деле я просто очень внимательно ее прочитал. И там есть предложение "_С другой стороны, блокировки SIRead часто должны сохраняться и после фиксирования транзакции, пока не будут завершены другие, наложившиеся на неё транзакции_".  И да, в других СУБД все может быть совершенно по другому, половина того о чем вы писали в части СУБД выполняется вообще не за счет блокировок